# How can I convert this query from SQL to linq

Tags: linq

Can anyone help me converting this SQL query to linq:

```
select fi.CreatedOn, fi.Id 
from Branch br 
inner join Asset a on br.Id = a.BranchId 
inner join Inspection i on i.AssetId = a.Id
inner join FormInstance fi on i.FormInstanceId = fi.Id 
inner join [User] u on u.HomeBranchId = br.Id
where br.Id like 'xxx'
group by fi.CreatedOn, fi.Id
order by fi.CreatedOn desc
```

This is what I got so far, but I don't understand how to do the group by part

```
from fi in model.FormInstance                                                                      
join ins in model.Inspections on fi.Id equals ins.FormInstanceId 
join a in model.Assets on ins.AssetId equals a.Id
join br in model.Branches on a.BranchId equals br.Id
join usr in model.Users on br.Id equals usr.HomeBranchId
where br.Id == gBranchId 
group fi by fi.Id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed defining right grouping key.

```cs
query =
    from fi in model.FormInstance                                                                      
    join ins in model.Inspections on fi.Id equals ins.FormInstanceId 
    join a in model.Assets on ins.AssetId equals a.Id
    join br in model.Branches on a.BranchId equals br.Id
    join usr in model.Users on br.Id equals usr.HomeBranchId
    where br.Id == gBranchId 
    group fi by new { fi.CreatedOn, fi.Id } into g
    select g.Key;

query = query.OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedOn);
```